# Linking to Users Profile Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm creating a profile for registered users using devise, and once they register it automatically creates a profile, My problem is, Inside the dashboard, I want to link to their profile and unsure what parameters I need to pass into the path to satisfy the id paramter?

User Model:

```
class User 
  has_one :student_profile, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Profile Model :

```
class StudentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates_associated :user

    def completed_profile?
        self.first_name.present? && self.last_name.present?
    end

end
```

I am using scaffold generated code for the controllers and untouched?

Inside my View Html.erb file I wanted to use the logged in users profile to be passed in so they can view or edit it.

```
 <%= link_to "View Profile", student_profile_path(@student_profile), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

However it is displaying the error missing [:id], Which I understand, but I am unsure what to pass into the "Student_profile_path()" link.

Do I need to update the show method in the profile controller?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what was printed when you run `rake routes` in your terminal?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response, In rake routes I see `student_profile_path GET /student_profiles/:id(.:format) student_profiles#show'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `@student_profile` is not present I think, if you want to show the student profile of current_user, let's use:

```
 <%= link_to "View Profile", student_profile_path(current_user.student_profile), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

**Update**

To make sure the `student_profile` is existing for every user, you can create a default student_profile when create a user, the code will be like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Your current code
  before_create :build_student_profile
end
```

So the `student_profile` will be built up with `user`

Then you need another step to complete this for created users, run this in your `rails console`

```
User.where.not(id: StudentProfile.pluck(:user_id)).find_each{ |user| user.create_student_profile }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, When I try your code I am getting the following error  'No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"student_profiles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]'

Comment: Hey, that means the current_user doesn't have any student_profile, so check out my update

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help, This is somewhat working now, however my problem is that, I will have users that will not have a student profile generated, Will depend on the type of user upon signup, So if a company registers, it creates a company page, An issue I am having with your code is, It is creating two user profiles now, and using the id below the one created for the user with the details. E.g. The link is linking to 8, but the users profile id is actually 9

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you are getting student_profile object in @student_profile

```
<%= link_to "View Profile",  student_profile_path(id: @student_profile.id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, No luck, Still getting an error saying "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: you are getting  "`id' for nil:NilClass" error because your  @student_profile object is nil. try to get current_user.student_profile.id and replace it with @student_profile.id like this 
<%= link_to "View Profile",  student_profile_path(id: current_user.student_profile.id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>

Comment: Hi Navin, I understand that, But I am unsure what to pass into this position, I was hoping someone here could help me.

Comment: please check my updated comment. replace the link with this
<%= link_to "View Profile", student_profile_path(id: current_user.student_profile.id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>

Comment: Still getting the error "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: So your current user doesn't have any student_profile yet. try to create current user's student profile first and add a condition before the link you have used to "view profile" that it is available only for those current_users who have their student_profile present.